# R function works on individual column but not with apply

Tags: r, matrix, apply, xts

I have the following problem. I created this simple function to remove the last 2 non-NA values from a vector (xts). It works perfectly.

```
library(xts)
last2na <- function(x) { x[which(is.na(lag(x,-2)))] <- NA; return(x) }
```

However when I try to apply to the column of a matrix (xts) it does nothing to the matrix itself. But if I apply the function individually to each column, then it does work.

For instance, take the following matrix:

```
d <- xts(matrix(1:14, ncol=2), Sys.Date()+1:7)
d[5:7,1] <- NA
d[7,2] <- NA
```

If I apply the function to each column, for instance the 2nd:

```
last2na(d[,2])
```

I get the right result (i.e. replace last 2 non-NA value with NA). But if I use apply:

```
apply(d, 2, last2na)
```

then nothing happens. I am returned the original matrix d with no change. I do not understand what the problem is.

Can somebody please help me with this? thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to see what's going on is to add `print(str(x))` to your `last2na` function. Or plain replace it with `str`:

```
str(d[,2])
# An ‘xts’ object on 2014-12-14/2014-12-20 containing:
#   Data: int [1:7, 1] 8 9 10 11 12 13 NA
#   Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
#   xts Attributes:  
#  NULL
```

Versus:

```
apply(d, 2, str)
#  Named int [1:7] 1 2 3 4 NA NA NA
#  - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:7] "2014-12-14" "2014-12-15" "2014-12-16" "2014-12-17" ...
#  Named int [1:7] 8 9 10 11 12 13 NA
#  - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:7] "2014-12-14" "2014-12-15" "2014-12-16" "2014-12-17" ...
# NULL
```

You can see that `apply` is not looping on `xts` columns but on plain integer vectors and this is what is making `last2na` fail at its task.

The transformation si documented under `?apply`:

> If X is not an array but an object of a class with a non-null dim value (such as a data frame), apply attempts to coerce it to an array via as.matrix if it is two-dimensional (e.g., a data frame) or via as.array

So essentially, it's doing `apply(as.matrix(d), 2, last2na)`.

That's it as far as understanding what went wrong. If you are looking for a solution, I am not an expert with `xts` objects but I noticed that `lag(d, -2)` works on the whole "matrix" so you can use this trick of adding the lagged then removing it:

```
d <- d + lag(d, -2) - lag(d, -2)
```

- where the lag is `NA`, the addition will turn values into `NA`
- where the lag is not `NA`, adding then subtracting a value will have no effect.

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. You are right the issue is that apply works on xts objects by removing the xts structure (and therefore lag does not work on it). Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Looks like apply can't handle xts objects, and your function can't handle a matrix:

```
d <- as.matrix(d)
d
last2na(d[,2])
```

Here's an (inelegant, I admit) solution:

```
last2na_matrix <- function(x) {x[is.na(x[-1])] <- NA; x[is.na(x[-1])] <- NA; return(x) }

apply(d, 2, last2na_matrix)
```